# minishift update causes issues

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, minishift

I recently updated minishift on mac:

```
minishift update:
...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.6.1 ...
..
-- Finding server IP ... 
...
FAIL
   Error: could not start OpenShift container "origin"
   Details:
     No log available from "origin" container

Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster.
$ minishift version
minishift v1.12.0+daa0943
```

There is an issue with v3.6.1.

If I revert back to v3.6.0 with:

> brew cask reinstall minishift

OR

> minishift start --openshift-version=v3.6.0

With version v3.6.0, it works it and does not do Finding server IP ...

Please advise how to fix v3.6.1 issue with:

> No log available from "origin" container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you already had a Minishift instance which was in stopped state when you ran the update command. Because the newer version has v3.6.1 as the default OpenShift version you are seeing this issue. Minsihift recommends [1] deleting the current instance and then starting will fix the issue.

[1] https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/updating.html#update-instructions

Comment: thanks that worked, however with minishift delete, i had to re-create all my projects, not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Minishift is hosted within a VM.  Currently, this VM is replaced entirely on upgrade.

Have you considered trying the cluster backup and restore features?: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/backup_restore.html